# Need clarification with arduino syntax

Tags: library, c

I've been learning how to program this fine piece of equipment but i seem stuck. I came upon the "Knight rider" example where you are supposed to blink LED's from one side to another and i can't understand where some of the code comes from. For example:

```
byte ledPin[] = {4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
int ledDelay;
int direction = 1;
int currentLED  = 0;
unsigned long changeTime;
int pot = 2;
int i;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pinMode(ledPin[i], OUTPUT);
    }

    changeTime = millis();
}

void loop()
{
    ledDelay = analogRead(pot);

    if ((millis()- changeTime) > ledDelay)
    {
        changeLED();
        changeTime = millis();
    }
}


void changeLED()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin[i], LOW);
        Serial.print("i = ");
        Serial.println(i);
    }

    digitalWrite(ledPin[currentLED], HIGH);

    currentLED += direction;

    if (currentLED == 9)
    {
        direction = -1;
    }

    if (currentLED == 0)
    {
        direction = 1;
    }
}
```

In this code I don't  know where the "direction" variable is coming from I searched on the arduino reference page but can't find it. Are there other references where I could look or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from the program itself:

```
int direction = 1;
```

That means "Create a signed integer called 'direction' and assign it the value 1.

Answer (score 1):

You defined the `direction` variable on the top with:

```
int direction = 1;
```

Comment: Yes I am fully aware of that. But in the sketch it is coloured red, if i rename it to "dir_etc" for example it is not highlighted by the IDE.  So i'm sure there is more to it than just me defining it. Hope my explanation is clear enoght.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. What IDE are you using? It could be defined as a global variable in one of the files that you are including, but that sounds very unlikely to me. What files are you including in your project? Also (depending on your IDE) you might be able to right click on the variable and chose "View variable declaration" or something like that.

Comment: I'm using the official IDE v1.8.1 from the arduino site. Other than that i don't know to be using  any files for this sketch, but then again I'm just a beginner so i might be wrong. Also i can't find the "View variable declaration" you're  writing about.

Comment: Ok, so we ruled out a couple of things. I'm using the same IDE, but I haven't had a similar thing happen to me. Can you post a screenshot of how the code looks like (how the `direction` variable is colored)? And post the error message you receive?

Comment: Hope these images are clear enough   http://imageshack.com/a/img922/9182/9xd84Z.png http://imageshack.com/a/img923/8880/Fdx0x9.png

Comment: And i don't have any errors actually the sketch is running just fine I'm just trying to understand how the code works in order to modify it and it seemed strange that "direction" is highlighted red and i can't find it on the reference page.  Sorry for double post.

Comment: Aaa nice, the mystery is solved. All that means is some library author decided `direction` was a keyword (which is a horrible idea in my opinion). Searching and greping on my system says that this is person to blame: `./arduino/arduino-1.6.12/libraries/Stepper/keywords.txt` (I don't know what system you run, but it should be in a similar hierarchy where you have Arduino IDE installed).

Comment: This however is not a problem for you (except that it's highlighted). When you define a `direction` variable in your code your variable will be used because of how variable scope works. This **is not** a language keyword, you can't define a variable named `int` (you might know all of this, if so sorry). So that's it :) I'll provide more links in a new comment. Feel free to ask more.

Comment: You can make your own keywords when writing a library so they are highlighted in the IDE (and only there) to make things nicer, an in your case someone decided to make the word `direction` a keyword in their library :)

1) [Simple explanation of your case](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=159700.0)

2) [A bit more complex explanation](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=149418.msg1123031#msg1123031)

3) [Really detailed technical explanation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150226113643/http://acsweb.ucsd.edu/~sbliven/2012/01/arduino-ide-keywords)

Comment: As I said feel free to ask more, and thanks, I learned something myself today! :)

Comment: Marvelous! Thanks for the help and sorry for the late reply.